# How to force a SpanLabel to break it's String

Tags: codenameone

I'm currently designing the sidemenu of a new app.

The idea is to have an accordion with four containers inside which uses a TableLayout with two columns. The containers are filled with components grouping an icon (ScaleImageLabel) atop of a SpanLabel, the group being lead by a Button.

In order to have an homogeneous sidemenu, I want that each component has the same width, so I've put all in a setSameWidth, BUT, here is my problem: Some components have a longer text than others, and if one of them get in the first column, it won't break it's text.

The issue here is that the second row is thinner than the first, and thus some texts are contracted too much...

Is it a way to force a SpanLabel tobreak it's text ? With this, I should be able to have a good sidemenu for my new app.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `\n` if changing the text works for you.

Alternatively I would suggest using `TextArea` setting the UIID to `Label` and making it editable `false`. Then you can define the `columns` property for better control over line break.

Comment: After some tries, I'm getting back to a custom function that break my string, the columns in the TextArea were not working (maybe I've done something wrong, but it's no more a problem)

Comment: Try a lower number of columns than you would expect as columns > characters