# How to reduce the width of a TextArea used as String?

Tags: codenameone

Still on my sidemenu from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283696/how-to-force-a-spanlabel-to-break-its-string), I've resolve the non broking text with a custom function that modify the text.

Now I'm stuck with the width of the component. I've change it from a `SpanLabel` to a `TextArea` in order to have more control on it's behaviour, but here is my problem: the `TextArea` width is too large as shown on the screenshot (put a ContentContainer UIID on to see the space occupied by the `TextArea`).

[image]

As you can see, the first component has a too large `TextArea`. I've set the column count of the `TextArea` to the length of the firstRow + 1, but it doesn't seem to take it in account.

The component is `BorderLayout` with a non grow center `ScaleImageLabel` and the `TextArea` on south. Is it a way to have a better width for the `TextArea` ? I would have it aligned with the image and with the area wrapped close to the text, but I really don't know how to achieve this...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to use `GridLayout` for equal sizes or `TableLayout` with constraints for varying sizes for left and right components. It will prevent the TextArea from growing beyond a limit.

An example will be:

```
//GridLayout
Container cont = GridLayout.encloseIn(4, cmpL1, cmpR1, cmpL2, cmpR2)

//OR

//TableLayout with Constraint
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(2, 2);

Container cont = new Container(tl);
cont.add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(50), cmpL1);
cont.add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(50), cmpR1);
cont.add(cmpL2);
cont.add(cmpR2);
```

Comment: I fixed the table code since the first row defines the width you don't need a constraint on the second row. You also shouldn't reuse constraint instances...

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine with the widthPercentage :)